# How to make fluid settle

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've created an animation of wine pouring into a glass, the problem is after the simulation is done and the fluid still splashes outside and goes over itself in the glass. I want it to slowly settle down after the pour is complete

[image: example animation]

Comment: provide your blend file please

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhjdejZwULue3yyxs3X_vXkY1LtAQ3Ko/view?usp=sharing, Here's the link to download the file. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: normally you share the blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/ . I would load your file from google, if you wouldn't have set request access for it. So i will not look at it.

Comment: Opps my bad, i did not check the restricted part. I just tried uploading on blend-exchange but the file size is over 30 mb. I generated another link from my drive for the file, this time with no request access. Sorry for last time. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mQK08xDBHUuNTdt6t5lGvXXqUAmJ3r1C?usp=sharing

Comment: actually, I re-ran your simulation and I don't have any "slurping" over the edge of the glass.  The glass is rather full.  One thing you can consider i the Domain Diffusion section is the Surface Tension and viscosity, which can have an effect. Resolution below 100 can be another source of inaccuracy.   Also I often have to drop Liquid :: Particle_Radius below 1.0 for better outcomes.